# Number of combinations with small intersection

Tags: combinatorics, coding-theory, combinatorial-designs

I have set $S$ of $n$ elements. I want to understand, in how many ways can I choose $n/2$ elements - let each such choice be set $S_i$ - such that no two choices have more than $n/4$ elements in common i.e $|S_i\cap S_j|\leq n/4$.
I have been thinking about it and I think that it should be (polynomial) function in $n$ - for $n=4$, it is $6$, for $n=8$, I could write $10$ ways, but I don't have an expression for general growth. Any approach on how to proceed would appreciated.

Comment: This seems closely related (perhaps identical) to the notion of *packing designs* with parameters $t-(n,k,1)$ where $k=n/2$ is the block size and $t = \lfloor n/4 \rfloor + 1$ is the size of a subset that can be contained by at most one block (subset of $S$).  There is a general upper bound (sometimes met) called the Schönheim bound on the number of blocks in a packing design.  I think this might be of interest, so I'll find a reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looing for is known in the literature as a *constant weight binary bode* with length $n$, weight $n/2$ and distance $n/2$, if you interpret your subsets as binary vectors of length $n$.

One type of such code is constructed by taking a [Hadamard matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadamard_matrix) of order $n$, ignoring the row of all ones, and for each of the remaining $n-1$ rows, including two subsets: one corresponding to the locations of the $+1$'s, and the other for the locations of the $-1$'s. This shows that as long as a Hadamard matrix of order $n$ exists, then you can get $2n-2$ subsets. This confirms what you found for $n=4$. When $n=8$, you can get $14$ subsets: take the list of seven subset below, together with their complements.

```
(1, 2, 3, 4), 
(1, 2, 5, 6), (1, 3, 5, 7), (1, 4, 5, 8)
(1, 2, 7, 8), (1, 3, 6, 8), (1, 4, 6, 7)
```

It is conjectured that there exists a Hadamard matrix of order $n$ whenever $n$ is a multiple of $4$. This conjecture has been confirmed for all but $13$ possible orders up to $2000$. Furthermore, I do not know if these Hadamard matrix based codes are optimal. According to this [table of optimal constant weight binary codes](https://www.win.tue.nl/%7Eaeb/codes/Andw.html), the optimal constant weight codes with parameters $(n,n/2,n/2)$ are indeed achieved by the Hadamard construction for $n\le 32$.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer!